# Jquery does not load modal and the modal it's added by .html bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ajax

Guys, I'm new in programming and I need your help. Well, I'm using jquery ajax in order to get  json from a Rest Api I take that JSON and put it in a html string and then I added with .html. The problem is that I cannot get an event when I click a row in a table and I'm unable to display any modal.

```js
function casosCRM(){

    if($("#seccionPerfil").val()==""){
        $('#texto_popup_error').html("Debe ingresar seccion en la pestaña Perfil");
        $('#errorIngreso').modal('show');
    }else {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_crm.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                seccionPerfil: $("#seccionPerfil").val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (JSON) {
                if (JSON.resultado == "false") {
                    $('#texto_popup_error').html("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
                    $('#errorIngreso').modal('show');
                } else {
                    var j;
                    var i;
                    var options = '';
                    var optionsTable = '';

                    optionsTable += '<table id="tableCRM" class="table table-bordered table-hover">';
                    optionsTable += '    <thead class="btn-primary">';
                    optionsTable += '        <tr>';
                    optionsTable += '            <th>ID</th>';
                    optionsTable += '            <th>Cliente</th>';
                    optionsTable += '            <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>';
                    optionsTable += '            <th>Asignado a:</th>';
                    optionsTable += '        </tr>';
                    optionsTable += '    </thead>';
                    optionsTable += '    <tbody>';
                   
                    for (j = JSON.resultadoWS[0].resultado_busqueda.length-1; j >= 0 ; j--) {

                        optionsTable += '        <tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="'+ j +'" data-target="#CRMmodal' + j + '">';
                        optionsTable += '            <td>' + j + '</td>';
                        optionsTable += '            <td>' + JSON.resultadoWS[0].resultado_busqueda[j].cliente + '</td>';
                        optionsTable += '            <td>' + JSON.resultadoWS[0].resultado_busqueda[j].fecha_ingreso + '</td>';
                        optionsTable += '            <td>' + JSON.resultadoWS[0].resultado_busqueda[j].asignado+ '</td>';
                        optionsTable += '        </tr>';
                        //alert(j);

                        options += '<div id="' + j + '" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CRMModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">';
                        //alert(options);
                        options += '<div class="modal-header">';
                        options += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>';
                        options += '<h1>Información CRM: Casos/Tickets</h1>';
                        options += '<div id="CRMCaso" class="modal-body"></div>';
                        options += '<div id="Casos" class="modal-body"></div>';
                        options += '<div class="modal-footer">';
                        options += '<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>';
                        options += '</div>';
                        options += '</div>';
                        //Input de cliente
                        options += '<div class="hr"></div>';
                        options += '<div class="b-row">';
                        options += '    <div class="span12">';
                        options += '       <div class="field">';
                        options += '            <i class="fa fa-child icon-right"></i>';
                        options += '            <input name="caso' + j + '" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="' + 'Cliente: ' + JSON.resultadoWS[0].resultado_busqueda[j].cliente
                            + '" readonly="readonly" >';
                        options += '        </div>';
                        options += '    </div>';
                        options += '</div>';
                        options += '<div class="hr"></div>';


                        //Input descripcion

                        options += '<div class="b-row">';
                        options += '    <div class="span12">';
                        options += '       <div class="field">';
                        options += '            <i class="fa fa-child icon-right"></i>';
                        options += '            <input name="descripcion' + j + '" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="' + 'Descripción: ' + JSON.resultadoWS[0].resultado_busqueda[j].descripcion
                            + '" readonly="readonly" >';
                        options += '        </div>';
                        options += '    </div>';
                        options += '</div>';

  
                    optionsTable += '    </tbody>';
                    optionsTable += '</table>';
                    optionsTable += '</div>';
                    optionsTable += '</br>';
                    optionsTable += '</br>';
                    optionsTable += options;

                    //alert(optionsTable);
                    //Inyecta codigo html al DOM
                    $('#opcionesReferencias2').html(optionsTable);
```

```html
<div id="opcionesReferencias3"   class="btn-group-vertical-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
</div>
```

I'm trying to show the modal using $("#1").modal('show') and does not work either the event in clic.

Comment: An element id name cannot start with a number! Its a start, not sure that will fixe your problem.

Comment: Thanks RafH, I have changed it to id="mod '  +  j +  ' " in order to have $("mod1").modal('show'); but has not worked. :(